# My film camera suddenly rolled back to the 1st frame

Tags: 35mm, negative-film, film-cameras

my kyocera p mini 3 film camera suddenly rolled back to 1 and as far as i can remember:

1. it was on its 18th shot
2. i never opened the back (since i know that it will reset back to 1)
3. i never pressed the rewind button
4. the last time i used it was monday then kept it in its bag then i just found out today (saturday) that it was rolled back to the 1st frame

I really dont know what to do as of the moment & also won’t do anything first.

Should I still continue shooting with this roll of film or just get it developed?